# Where can I find Obsidian in the Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have looked *everywhere* for lava or obsidian in 0.7.1. I've looked all the way from top to bottom and all around, in about a 100 block diameter, but I can't find any. Where can I get some?

Answer (score 3):

In the Pocket Edition, lava is incredibly rare, and natural obsidian is thus even rarer. Many seeds will not have natural obsidian, and some may not even have any significant amounts of lava.

Apparently, one seed that will work is "herobrine".

Answer (score 3):

You can get obsidian by making the nether reactor. When the nether is over the nether structure will turn into obsidian.

Answer (score 1):

Obsidian only appears when lava source block touches water. Obsidian never appears as part of world generation. Only on the coincidence of a underground water lake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a seed goldenvolcano which has lava. However if you enter the nether when you come out there is obsidian that you can mine.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the nether with a friend by duplicating gold, iron and diamonds. Then make the nether reactor and then mine the reactor and you get obsidian.

Comment: How are you going to get to the nether "by duplicating gold, iron and diamonds"? You need obsidian for getting to the nether.

Comment: @Arperum this is a question about pocket edition which doesn't have a nether, you build a nether reactor whose elements turn to obsidian when the reaction is finished.

Comment: @waxeagle thanks for the information, didn't know that, I assumed it was mostly identical to the pc version.