# How do you get obsidian from lava and water?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have found lava right next to water, but when they touch it just makes cobblestone - I'm trying to get obsidian.

Comment: Water has to flow onto stationary lava (source block).

Comment: Is this not exactly http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123315/where-can-i-find-obsidian-in-the-pocket-edition?

Comment: @fbueckert It's not quite the same.  That seems to ask for where one can FIND it while this one asks how one MAKES it.

Answer (score 6):

Right, the answer is water flow on a lava source.  Water/lava interactions work like this:

Water flow + lava source = Obsidian
Lava flow + water source = Stone
Water flow + lava flow = Cobblestone

Answer (score 4):

You dump water *on* a lava block - an easy way is to put the lava in a 1 block pit, and flood it with water from the surrounding area. This will destroy the lava and leave an obsidian block behind. Considering that obsidian is hard to mine, its better to use a bucket to take the lava, move it where you need to, and then water it.

Comment: Also note that only lava Source blocks can turn into obsidian, the 'flow' blocks turn into cobblestone

Comment: But when I did it it was lava flow to water source